# Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS the world "normal" appaer in the top of some windows

Tags: gnome-shell

[image]

the world "normal" appears at the top of some windows
I'm using

Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS

GNOME Shell 42.2

and the only extension that I'm currently using is gnome-clipboard@b00f.github.io

Comment: that's normal, don't worry (sorry, couldn't resist the joke). Okay, posting a real answer in a sec.

Comment: joke appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Found [this solution on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/e1no4w/the_word_normal_show_up_in_all_of_my_windows_on/):

> open nvidia-settings and look for an option like "GSYNC indicator", check it off. It would say "G-SYNC" if it's in GSYNC-mode instead of normal mode

Let me know if that helps! You may need to reboot for the settings change to take effect.

Comment: Thinks. it worked, but what does this option do anyway am I missing anything by disabling it